# AngularJS typeahead with integers

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead, angularjs-bootstrap

I am using [typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) from Angular Bootstrap. Sample plunker provided by them is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XOcKFS0UoCr3QcDb3KIH?p=preview). As you can see `$scope.states` is filled by the array:

```
$scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', ... ];
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

---

However, if I change the plunker to an array of numbers, as [in this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dGWv9BqTjCqxvd4Wt1A3?p=preview); although you can move your cursor, and it returns you the values starting with the number you have typed; you can't see the content on the dropdown and it looks weird:

[image]

Is there a way to make typeahead work with integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in the typeahead implementation (see https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1777) that was fixed yesterday via https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/09678b1260dadb0a399d8e71fc2e1f5597c9ca31. The fix will be part of the next release (0.11.0), for now you can monkey-patch your version based on the change done in the referenced commit.

Comment: thanks! I recenlty opened #1781, closing it as well.